# Jquery ajax not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is working in chrome,safari but its not working in firefox.

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loginform").on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('#loading').html("Loading....");

        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "POST",         
            data: new FormData(this), 
            contentType:false,     
            cache: false,            
            processData:false, 
            async:false,                    
            success: function(data)  
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#message").html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;

    }));

});
</script>
```

Can anyone solve this issue??? I have one more same script in the same page only url is different but its working fine,but this script is not working .Iam getting empty data .But in chrome,safari its working fine.

My Html Code :

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="loginform" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password"> Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" name="user_rememberme" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
              <div id="loading"></div>
              <div id="message"></div>
              <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Login</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Try `$(this).serializeArray();` instead of `new FormData(this)`

Comment: @PradeepSingh what happens if he has a input type file?

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: Check your console first and see if there is anything wrong or conflicting anything

Comment: `it's not working` - clearly because you wouldn't ask a question if it was. Describing what you **do** observe (console error log etc) is far more helpful

Comment: I tried $(this).serializeArray(); but it also not worked. In console there is no error

Comment: what version of firefox do you use?

Comment: could it be a closure problem on your definition of the success function?

Answer (score 3):

Never use `async:false` in ajax call unless you knows specifically wat you are doing.The problem is that `async:false` freezes the browser until ajax call is complete (either error or success).set it to true or remove it (by default it is true).Implement error block too and check if its an error from server side

```
success: function(data)  
{
$('#loading').hide();    
$("#message").html(data);
},error:function(data){
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: I tried removing async:false and there is nothing in console.No error.but still its not working

Comment: try firebug and check the ajax call is going correctly to login.php ,check for status 500 /404 errors

Comment: status is 200 there is no error .Iam getting empty data.

Comment: Then check the login.php ,it is not echoing any data

Comment: Php script is working fine.Its working in chrome ,safari . @ coolguy

Comment: share your `login.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loginform").on('submit',(function(e) {
        dta = $(this).serialize();
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#loading').html("Loading....");

        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "POST",         
            data:dta,                                
            success: function(data)  
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#message").html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;

    }));

});
</script>
```

Comment: what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: firefox 42.0 @  madalin ivascu

Comment: I have updated my code u can see the html code now @  madalin ivascu

Comment: But still its not working...... No errors in console Status is 200   @  madalin ivascu

Comment: i think the problem is with your mozila instalation/plugings